# Is the range of $f=\text{constant}$ the empty set when the constant approaches infinity?

Tags: functions

Consider the function $f=5$, which only outputs $5$. I'm unsure if my notation is proper, but let me denote $f$'s range as $\operatorname{range}(f)=[5,5]$.

Now, instead of $k=5$, we can increase the value of the constant $k$. As $k$ approaches infinity, we can imagine that the functions graph gets elevated towards infinity. Speaking non-rigorously, I assume that in the limiting case the graph hits the ceiling of the cartesian coordinate system, and thus $f$ loses its range. Or rather, $f$'s range becomes the empty set $\emptyset$. My resoning is that the range $[k,k]$ becomes $(\infty, \infty)$ $-$ which obviously is a set that contains nothing.

To summarize, I'd write this as
$\operatorname{range}(f)\rightarrow\emptyset$ as $f=k\rightarrow\infty$.

My question is, is my reasoning correct?

If it isn't, how can one denote $f$'s range as an interval as $k\rightarrow\infty$, and how do would you argue that the size of the interval is nonzero?

Comment: if $f$ is constant, say $f(x)=k$, the range of $f$ is the set $\{k\}$. I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. For every $k\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{k\}$ has a nonempty image $\{k\}$. But how do you define the limit of a set? In particular, what do you mean by $\lim_{k\to\infty}{\{k\}}$?

Comment: No, it is not. For every $k$ the range of $f$ is a single value. So, the limit of the size of the range if $k$ approaches $\infty$ , is $1$ , not $0$.

Comment: This question assumes that $\emptyset$ is an interval.

Comment: why will graph lose it's range while trying to hit ceiling of cartesian system , at least it will be at some height from floor of cartesian system i.e. x-axis while trying to do so?

Comment: This sequence of functions just doesn't converge to any limit function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Hence there is no "limit case" we can consider the range of. — If anything you'd have to extend $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ or $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ and equip that with a suitable topology. In that case the limit function is $f(x)=\infty$ and the range $\{\infty\}$ still contains a single element.

Comment: You mean sequence of functions $f_n$(x) = n . As n tends to infinity is same as lim n which is infinity not a particular value nor empty.